# remove duplicate values from the column of the table without deleting the row of the table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have written this code

```
SELECT  

cast(isnull(x.hc,'') AS VARCHAR(500)) as A,

Case
When cast(isnull(p.dg,'') AS VARCHAR(500)) = '0' then ''
else cast(isnull(p.dg,'') AS VARCHAR(500))
End as B, 

Case
When cast(isnull(h.cno,'') as varchar(500)) = '0' then ''
else cast(isnull(h.cno,'') as varchar(500))
End as C, --added

cast(isnull(p.vol,0) as varchar(500)) as D,

cast(isnull(p.weigh,0) as varchar(500)) as E

FROM ship g
inner join S_M d on d.ship_id = g.ship_id
left join Pack h on h.ship_id = g.ship_id
left join pack_d p on p.pack_id = h.pack_id
left join comm x on x.comm_id = p.comm_id
WHERE g.ship_pk = @ship_pk 
GROUP BY  cast(isnull(x.hc,'') AS VARCHAR(500)), cast(isnull(p.dg,'') AS VARCHAR(500)), cast(isnull(h.cno,'') as varchar(500)), cast(isnull(p.vol,0) as varchar(500)), cast(isnull(p.weigh,0) as varchar(500))
```

Which gives me the ouput as

```
A     B      C        D        E

123   Yes    AB456    26.34    28.45
123   Yes    AB687    26.34    28.45
125   No     AB794    22.58    24.36
125   No     AB456    22.58    24.36
125   No     AB687    22.58    24.36
```

How Can I change my code above so that I can get the Output as

```
A     B      C        D        E

123   Yes    AB456    26.34    28.45
             AB687    26.34    28.45
125   No     AB794    22.58    24.36
             AB456    22.58    24.36
             AB687    22.58    24.36
```

How can I remove the duplicate values from the first two columns of the table
As shown above? 
I am not deleting any row here, instead just removing the duplicate values and keeping that field blank.

How can I do that?

Comment: This would be very complicated to write in sql, why don't you do it on the program's side, you can remember the values of a and b and not display them if they haven't changed from previous value.

Comment: yes, I agree with @xception, this is a formatting issue not a data retrieval issue

Comment: Why group by with no aggregate instead of distinct? You could; `case row_number() over (partition by a,b order by a,b) when 1 then b else '' end,` for a & b

Comment: Thanks Alex. Issue is resolved :)